# Android posting data to mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, web-services

i am trying to post data through android forms to mysql database. i am posting data to a PHP script hosted on the server. i am getting null values in MYSQL. the webservice is getting called but it is getting blank data  below is my android code code:

```
package com.register;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.app.Activity;

public class Register extends Activity {




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        EditText email_id = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.email_id) ;
        EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1) ;

        final String email = email_id.getText().toString();
        final String fullname = name.getText().toString();
        final String mpassword = password.getText().toString();



        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //postData();
          HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xyz/register.php");

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", fullname));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mpassword));
               httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }

    }
});

    }
```

Below is my PHP code :

```
mysql_connect("server","user","password");
mysql_select_db("testms");
$email =   $_POST['email'];
$name =    $_POST['name'] ;
$password = $_POST['password'] ;

$query_add="INSERT INTO  users (`email` ,`name` ,`password` )
VALUES ('".$email."','".$name."', '".$password."')";
$query_exec=mysql_query($query_add) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_close();      

    }
```

Comment: Where does the error happen? Is your app is sending the data OK? Is PHP receiving it OK, and processing it properly? Which fields are coming through as NULL? Have you run your generated SQL from PHP directly in the database?

Comment: Posting large chunks of code and expecting the SO community to debug for you is frowned upon around here. What have you tried? Have you dumped the POST collection on the server? Have you tried inserting constants? Also, you code is vulnerable to SQL injection and magic quote bugs.

Comment: and what are you getting on PHP interface? try do debug $_REQUEST and $_POST with `var_deubug`

Comment: wild guess: set the content type header?

Comment: question using my_sql extension consider to be deprecated on so as well.

Comment: @Seva Alekseyev yes i have tested the constants both in android as well as PHP code. both are working fine. but when i post data through android ui, the null value gets inserted

Comment: Dooes PHP throw an error like "Index not found"? If not, it looks like your Java is sending over a blank query string value.

Comment: @user1260028 is there anyway to see what strings is my java code sending? i think that exactly is the problem since the query is getting fired but with blank values

Comment: Before you HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); output it to logcat or some other form of console. Toast is slow but it works for end of the world output :P

Comment: Try just inserting constant values into the fields like "Test1", "test2", test3" for the email, name and password. See if that works. If it does, your not getting the values properly from the form.

Comment: I would also try to just insert the raw post with headers, paramters and all as a string in a table. Just for debugging.

Comment: @user1260028 the constant are working perfectly fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should work, but it is not tested - I just copied over from a project I am working on.  I will update the MySQL interaction in the PHP section to mysqli (the CORRECT method) in a couple minutes and I will just edit my answer. For now, just know that using mysql_* is depreciated, and you should really sanitize all entries to and from your database. Anyway, give this a whirl:

Java:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // generate your params:
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", fullname));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", mpassword));

    // send them on their way
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://xyz/register.php");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValueParams));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

PHP (depreciated/unsanitized):

```
<?php 

    $connection = mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password")or die(mysql_error());
    $selection = mysql_select_db("database", $connection)or die(mysql_error());

    // You should echo these variables back to your app
    // so you know they are sending.
    // echo "Received: " . $email . " - " . $name . " - " . $password;
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $insert = "INSERT INTO users('email','name','password') VALUES('$email','$name','$password')";
    $run = mysql_query($insert)or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

A Better PHP Example:

```
<?php   
    $mysqli_connection = new mysqli("hostname", "username", "password", "database");
    if ($mysqli_connection->connect_errno) {
        echo ("Connection Failure");
        exit();
    }

    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $insert = "INSERT INTO users('email','name','password') VALUES('$email','$name','$password')";
    if ($run = $mysql_connection->query($insert)) {
        echo 'Success';
        $run->free();
        $mysql_connection->close();
    } else {
        echo 'Error Inserting Content';
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the $_REQUEST variable and grab the data before connecting to the database

```
$email =   $_REQUEST ['email'];  
$name =    $_REQUEST ['name'] ;  
$password = $_REQUEST ['password'] ;    

mysql_connect("server","user","password");  
mysql_select_db("testms"); 
$query_add="INSERT INTO  users (`email` ,`name` ,`password` )  VALUES ('".$email."','".$name."', '".$password."')";  $query_exec=mysql_query($query_add) or die(mysql_error());   
mysql_close();              
}
```

I usually send back some data for debugging purposes.

```
echo "some test string";
```

In your application do the following:
Just for the sake of knowing, check the response from the server:

```
int ResponseCode = response.getStatusLine();

HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
if( resEntity != null ){
    if( EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).equalsIgnoreCase("some test string") )
    {
        ...do something
    }
    resEntity.consumeContent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[...]INTO  users (`email` ,`name` ,`password` )[...] it seems like yout qotations are wrong. Use '' or "", NOT ``

Comment: I think those quotes are still acceptable in MySQL. Don't remember if they cause an issue in SQL. His issues seems to be that he is getting blank values.

Comment: Backquotes around field/table names (not values) are prefectly OK in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

try moving the getting the text field data on your button click event, the variable is final and it already have the data after the creation of the activity.